# Invalid server response UWP banner ad error

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have UWP which uses In-app ad. It shows test ads, but it doesn't show real ads when deployed to windows server. I am getting Invalid server response.

> error Code: InvalidServerResponse Error Message: Invalid server
>   response

I have followed [AdControl in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net) to create uwp ad in my app. Any work around?

Comment: Are u still using the test application id?

Comment: No I am using real application and ad Unit.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @EnriqueA.PineloNovelo yeah, this appear if the ad control doesn't have advertisement. otherwise, it works fine. (I had limited my ads to specific categories).